# NavigationManager.NavigateTo() vs NavigateToLogout()?

Tags: blazor-server-side

There's the specific calls of `NavigateToLogin()` and `NavigateToLogout()`. So clearly they do something differne from `NavigateTo()`. So what is the difference?

You have to pass a url to each, so what is different from:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/logout");
```

and:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateToLogout("/logout");
```

And while we're at it, what is different for:

```
NavigationManager.NavigateToCore("/logout");
```